# Where can I download fedora 12?

Tags: system-installation, download, distributions

Does anyone know where to download Fedora 12 *.iso file today (mid June 2018)?

I have an old laptop computer from 2007 (an HP pavilion dv6000 series) that dual boots with a Linux distro.

Here are the specs:

- 20GB partition for Linux
- 2GB RAM
- 32-bit arch CPU

Fed28 will freeze soon after login so I thought I would install Fed12, contemporary to Ubuntu 9.10 that worked flawlessly when I first tried it, many years ago. Unfortunately, with a snail Internet connection I've failed multiple times to download it from [the Fedora Project Archives](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/).

Can anyone suggest a website or torrent repository where I can safely and entirely download the iso from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/12/Fedora/i386/iso/

```
Icon  Name                                               Last modified      Size  Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory                                                        -   
[   ] Fedora-12-i386-CHECKSUM                            2009-11-12 06:23  1.5K  
[   ] Fedora-12-i386-DVD.iso                             2009-11-09 00:02  3.0G  
[   ] Fedora-12-i386-disc1.iso                           2009-11-09 00:12  691M  
[   ] Fedora-12-i386-disc2.iso                           2009-11-09 00:12  694M  
[   ] Fedora-12-i386-disc3.iso                           2009-11-09 00:13  693M  
[   ] Fedora-12-i386-disc4.iso                           2009-11-09 00:14  689M  
[   ] Fedora-12-i386-disc5.iso                           2009-11-09 00:14  289M  
[   ] Fedora-12-i386-netinst.iso                         2009-11-08 23:58  202M
```

Comment: Thank you for the link. I downloaded the iso files (Fedora-12-i386-DVD, Fedora-12-i686-Live.iso) then used Unetbootin to create a multiboot usb stick. Unfortunately, when I reboot the PC with the USB stick inserted, the BIOS can't boot in either fedora or ubuntu 10. Keeps saying `root not found, sleeping forever`

Comment: That warrants an entirely new question, in my opinion.